# Leer un valor de Array Multidimensional en PHP

Tags: php, array

Estoy trabajando con el REST API de WooCommerce que me general el siguiente array de Productos

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 17758
            [name] => Product Name
            [slug] => Product Slug
            [permalink] => https://site.es/product/
            [date_created] => 2023-02-11T18:16:01
            [status] => publish            
            [description] => Descripción del Producto
            [short_description] => Descripción Corta del Producto
            [sku] => XXX
            [price] => 499
            [regular_price] => 599
            [sale_price] => 499
            [downloads] => Array
                (
                )
            [dimensions] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [length] => 60
                    [width] => 60
                    [height] => 85
                )
            [categories] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 77
                            [name] => 60 CM
                            [slug] => 60-cm
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 76
                            [name] => Lavavajillas
                            [slug] => lavavajillas
                        )

                )

            [tags] => Array
                (
                )
```

Lo recorro con un foreach normal `foreach ($products as $product)`, si quiero el nombre de un producto lo obtengo así:

```
echo $product->name;
```

El problema lo tengo cuando quiero ver el nombre de una categoría. **categories** es el array que tiene mas arrays dentro, yo debo obtener **Lavavajillas** como resultado. He probado con lo siguiente sin poder acceder a esa propiedad.

```
echo $product->categories->name;
echo $product->categories->1->name;
echo $product->categories->"1"->name;
echo $product->categories->[1]->name;
```

Como debo acceder a ese tipo de arrays dentro de un array??

Comment: $product->categories[1]->name   ????

Comment: Gracias @Yussef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que lo entiendas rápido, debes concatenar el nombre del array con el numero o nombre del siguiente array y luego la propiedad

```
echo $product->categories[1]->name;
```

---

[Edito] Estaba respondiendo y no me fije en el comentario que Yussef había hecho.